# cakephp model foreign keys not working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.4

I have 2 tables:

```
-> model_tickets 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detail_models` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ModelTicket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `taille` enum('8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20') NOT NULL,
  `police` enum('Impact','courier new','times new roman','comic sans ms') NOT NULL,
  `bold` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `italic` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ModelTicket_id` (`ModelTicket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;

-> detail_models
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `model_tickets` (
  `ModelTicket_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_model` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modif` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ModelTicket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

The code in  model ModelTicket.php :

```
var $hasMany = array('DetailModel' =>
    array('className' => 'DetailModel',
        'conditions' => '',
        //'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
        'limit' => '5',
        'foreignKey' => 'ModelTicket_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'exclusive' => false,
        'finderQuery'   => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Error Display:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ModelTicket.id' in 'field list'
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very expert at CAKEPHP but if your table is model_tickets shouldnt your model be named like "Model_Ticket.php" instead of ModelTicket.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Your ModelTicket.php doesn't follow the standard on how to name your primary key. It should be called "id".

If you can't change the column name then you can modify the model and let it know that your primary key is not "id" but "ModelTicket_id"

```
public $primaryKey = 'ModelTicket_id';
```

More info [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey)